# Amicable Numbers

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am struggling with optimizing these functions that I have used to calculate the sum of the amicable pairs under 10000. An [amicable pair](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AmicablePair.html) is a pair (a, b) where the sum of the divisors of "a" excluding "a" itself equals b and the sum of the divisors of "b" excluding "b" itself equals "a".

I.e. divisors of 220 are 1, 2, 4, 5, 10, 11, 20, 22, 44, 55 and 110: The sum of which is 284. And the sum of the divisors of 284 (1, 2, 4, 71 and 142) equals 220.

My code is:

```
import math
def Divisorsbaritself(x):
    divList = [1]
    y = 2
    while y <= math.sqrt(x):
        if x % y == 0:
            divList.append(y)
            divList.append(int(x / y))
        y += 1
    return sum(divList)

def amicable():
    solution = []
    for i in range(10000):
        if Divisorsbaritself(Divisorsbaritself(i)) == i:
            solution.append(i)
    return sum(solution)

print amicable()
```

I need help with understanding why the amicable function is not working. To me it makes logical sense that the `if Divisorsbaritself(Divisorsbaritself(i)) == i:` condition is the right condition to include `i` in the list, but it is giving me 40285, rather than 31626, the answer.

Comment: One potential bug.  What happens if `i` is a perfect square?

Answer (score 2):

If `Divisorsbaritself(i)==i` you shouldn't count `i`.

```
def amicable():
    solution = []
    for i in range(10000):
        if Divisorsbaritself(i)!=i and Divisorsbaritself(Divisorsbaritself(i)) == i:
            solution.append(i)
    return sum(solution)
```

But you should also fix the bug that would be an issue if i is a perfect square and in an amicable pair.

You can improve this with list comprehensions.

```
def amicable():
    solution = [i for i in xrange(10000) if Divisorsbaritself(i)!=i and Divisorsbaritself(Divisorsbaritself(i)) == i]
    return sum(solution)
```

Comment: Oh that's really cool! I didn't realize you could do that in a list

Answer (score 1):

They're amicable numbers only if they're *different.* So if `divsum(i)` is equal to `i`, then that's not included, despite the fact that means that `divsum(divsum(i))` also equals `i`.

In addition, your current check counts the square root of a perfect square *twice,* even though it's only *one* factor.

And, on top of that, I wouldn't be using a list then summing it at the end when you can simply use an accumulator. And it's *usually* faster to do multiplication than square roots so you can change the `while` loop to take that into account.

Finally, for the love of whatever deities you believe in, *comment your code!* It'll make it *so* much easier to understand what's going on, both for others and for yourself six months down the track.

Incorporating those changes gives you the following `DivisorsBarItself` function:

```
def DivisorsBarItself(num):
    # Maintain sum of factors.

    divSum = 1

    # Go through every integer up to but excluding sqrt(num).

    testnum = 2
    while testnum * testnum < num:
        # If factor, add it and the complement (guaranteed integer).

        if num % testnum == 0:
            divSum += testnum + num/testnum
        testnum += 1

    # If perfect square, add the square root once.

    if testnum * testnum == num:
        divSum += testnum

    # Return the sum.

    return divSum
```

Fixing the logic for detecting amicable numbers and using a sum rather than a list gives you:

```
def AmicableSum():
    # Set sum to zero and process all numbers below 10,000.

    solution = 0
    for num in range(10000):
        # Get the "friend", add only if different and f(f(x)) = x.

        numFriend = DivisorsBarItself(num)
        if numFriend != num and DivisorsBarItself(numFriend) == num:
            solution += num

    return solution

print AmicableSum()
```

which gives the correct result of `31626`.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the bug now by going:

```
def Divisorsbaritself(x):
    divList = [1]
    y = 2
    while y <= math.sqrt(x):
        if x % y == 0:
            if y is not int(x/y):
                divList.append(y)
                divList.append(int(x / y))
            else:
                divList.append(y)
        y += 1
    return sum(divList)
```

Comment: Note you can use `x//y` instead of `int(x/y)`.

Answer (score 0):

I have written the whole thing you said as a function

```
def devisor(a):
   listOfFactors=[]
   for possibleFactor in range(1,a):
       if a%x==0:
           listOfFactors.append(possibleFactor)
   sumOfFactors=0
   for item in z:
       sumOfFactors+=item
   factorsOfNewSumAddedUp=0
   for x in range(1,sumOfFactors):
       if temp%x==0:
           factorsOfNewSumAddedUp+=x
   if a==factorsOfNewSumAddedUp:
        print("this is a divisor")
```

Comment: Wait what are the problems with the code? I tried to be as clear as I could possibly be with the variable names. Are they too long?

Comment: Well, for one `temp` is never assigned.

Comment: Yea, its clear, but it doesn't follow pep-8. A quick example, your variable names should use snake case, not camel case.